# NSNumber from NSDate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsnumber

I'm attempting to get around a date validation that refuses to take anything earlier than tomorrow.
So far I have this:

```
NSDate *dateY = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-86400];
                // Negative one day, in seconds (-60*60*24)
NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate date]);
    // "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z", accurate assuming Z = +0000
NSLog(@"%@", dateY);
    // "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z", same accuracy (minus one day)
```

That's great, but `dateY` is not an `NSNumber`. I need an `NSNumber` for the comparison, but I can't find anything that works. (I don't even know how an `NSNumber` can be `2011-04-14 13:22:29 +0000`, anyway...)

I can use `NSDateFormatter` to convert an `NSDate` into an `NSString`, so if it would be possible to take that string and convert it to the required `NSNumber` (as opposed to directly converting the `NSDate` to an `NSNumber`, which I can't seem to find help with either), that would be fine.

---

```
- (BOOL)validateDueDate:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {
    NSDate *dateY = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-86400];
    NSNumber *tis1970 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[dateY timeIntervalSince1970]];
    NSLog(@"NSNumber From Date : %@", tis1970);
    NSLog(@"Date From NSNumber : %@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[tis1970 doubleValue]]);

    // Due dates in the past are not valid
    // Enforced that a due date has to be >= today's date
    if ([*ioValue compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        if (outError != NULL) {
            NSString *errorStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Due date must be today or later."] autorelease];
            NSDictionary *userInfoDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:errorStr forKey:@"ErrorString"];
            NSError *error = [[[NSError alloc]
                                initWithDomain:TASKS_ERROR_DOMAIN
                                code:DUEDATE_VALIDATION_ERROR_CODE
                                userInfo:userInfoDictionary] autorelease];
            *outError = error;
            }
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Right now, the user is not allowed to choose a date before tomorrow. `errorStr` lies. Before today makes more sense than before tomorrow as a rule for refusing to save the date, so I've been fighting with this thing to let me use yesterday in place of today, rather than looking any deeper.

Edit: Using `NSOrderedSame` allows any date to be selected without an error. That won't do.

Comment: if you want just to compare equality, you can use `[date isEqualToDate:dateY];`

Comment: Why do you need an NSNumber for the comparison? You already have an NSNumber to compare to? What does it represent?

Comment: What is ioValue? A number? A string?

Comment: (id *)ioValue just tells me that ioValue is a pointer to an id (not an id, which is an object pointer, but a pointer to an id). It could be a pointer to tour app delegate, or an NSTask, or a UITableView. I'd be surprised if any of those could be considered dates.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can convert an `NSDate` to an `NSNumber` like this:

```
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate date];
NSNumber *secondsSinceRefDate = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[aDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
```

and convert back like:

```
aDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[NSNumber doubleValue]];
```

Comment: for new folks (me), when converting back, the 'NSNumber' above is placeholder for your variable.  e.g., code above would read 'aDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[secondsSinceRefDate doubleValue]];'   // (thank you odrm)

Answer (score 1):

All that is needed to get a `NSNumber` is

```
NSDate *dateY = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-86400];
NSNumber *tis1970 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[dateY timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSLog(@"NSNumber From Date : %@", tis1970);
NSLog(@"Date From NSNumber : %@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[tis1970 doubleValue]]);
```

Comment: You are more than likely doing something wrong. Try copying and pasting my code exactly I am going to add an edit. It looks like you are calling timeIntervalSinceReferenceData on a `NSNumber` not a `NSDate`.

Comment: Add the code to your original question. We need to know what ioValue is and what you are really trying to accomplish. `NSNumber` may not even be the right solution for you.

Comment: POST YOUR CODE!!! seriously add your code, explain what you are trying to accomplish and I can guarantee you if it is logical you will get a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use `86400` to calculate date differences, because not all days have 86,400 seconds in them.  Use `NSDateComponents` instead:

```
- (BOOL)validateDueDate:(NSDate *)dueDate error:(NSError *)error {
  NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
  //adjust the components to tomorrow at the first instant of the day
  [components setDay:[components day] + 1];
  [components setHour:0];
  [components setMinute:0];
  [components setSecond:0];
  NSDate *tomorrow = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

  NSDate *earlierDate = [dueDate earlierDate:tomorrow];
  if ([earlierDate isEqualToDate:dueDate]) {
    //the dueDate is before tomorrow
    if (error != nil) {
      NSString *errorStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Due date must be today or later."] autorelease];
      NSDictionary *userInfoDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:errorStr forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
      *error = [[[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:TASKS_ERROR_DOMAIN code:DUEDATE_VALIDATION_ERROR_CODE userInfo:userInfoDictionary] autorelease];
    }
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

<sub>WARNING: code typed in a browser. *Caveat Implementor*</sub>